# Random walk on a square with its center

Tags: probability, graph-theory, conditional-probability, random-walk, random-graphs

A dog named Alfred is sitting in the corner $A$ of a square $ABCD$. A bone is
placed in the center $O$ of the square. We assume that Alfred moves randomly, following
the segments created by $OABCD$. We call $P_n$ the probability of Alfred reaching the bone
in the center $O$ for the first time after $n$ moves and $S_n$ the probability of Alfred reaching the center at least one time after $n$ moves.

The questions regarding this problem are:

(1) Compute $P_n$

(2) Find the link between $P_n$ and $S_n$ and compute $S_n$

(3) Calculate $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} S_n$

Now I understand that $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n} P_k$, and I have tried to find a formula for $P_n$ using matrices but I don't see a pattern emerging and without the help of wolfram alpha it would take me decades to do the calculations (which are a $5 \times 5$ matrix to the power of $n$). Can someone help me figure out how to compute $P_n$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a mistake with my reasoning, here is a fix :

If $X_n$ is the position at set $n$, we have :
\begin{align*}
P_n&=\mathbb P[X_n=O,X_1\neq O,\dots,X_{n-1}\neq O]\\
&=\mathbb P[X_n=O|X_{n-1}\neq O]\cdot\left(\prod_{k=2}^{n-1} \mathbb P[X_k\neq O | X_{k-1}\neq O]\right)\cdot \mathbb P[X_1\neq O]\\
&=\frac{1}{3}\cdot \left(\prod_{k=2}^{n-1} \frac{2}{3}\right) \cdot 1\\
&=\frac{2^{n-2}}{3^{n-1}}
\end{align*}

Comment: shouldn't that be $1/3$? bc you can reach e.g. D,B and O from A, but not C.

Comment: Yes it might, the problem is not incredibly well defined, lets say yes.

Comment: I don't get why do we have 2/3 in the recurrent formula.

Comment: @anton at each step from $A,B,C,D$ with probability $\frac13$ you reach $O$ and with probability $\frac23$ you are at one of $A,B,C,D$.  But I would have thought this gives   $P_n=(1-\frac{1}{3}) P_{n-1}$